# Write Arduino Serial output to file or program on PC

Tags: java, c++, matlab, arduino

So I've been looking around for a way to write from an Arduino directly onto a file on the PC, and basically I've found out there's no native way to do so. I wanted to do this in order to then read the file from a C++/Java program, and use the information in it. I also wanted to do this in real-time at some point, so it would be kind of like sending information from the Arduino over to the Java/C++ program for processing.

However, I've seen multiple people state on other forums that you can link the Serial output to some program running on the PC, and then use that program to write the output to a file. However, each time, they neglect to write out how exactly to do this.

The main purpose I wanted to write from the Arduino directly to a file was to read this file from another (Java/C++) program, so the above would be great for me. So how can I get the Serial output into a Java (much more preferably, as I might want to use Swing later) or C++ program, to then use this information in the program itself, or write it to a file? Real-time sending would be a great help.

If the above isn't possible, MATLAB might do, but to be clear, I would much rather be able to interface with Java/C++. Or both Java and MATLAB.

EDIT: To be more specific about what exactly I'd like to do, it is to sort of 'trigger' the Java program to read from the Serial output when a new line has been written (so it reads each line separately) and store it in a string in the Java program, then process it, all at once, and then sleep until another new line is written to the Serial port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone was looking for the easiest way to do this, it is hands down to ignore C++ and Java and use MATLAB.

There's a great short tutorial at [AllAboutEE](http://allaboutee.com/2011/07/04/how-to-send-data-from-the-arduino-to-matlab/) that I used and it solved most of my problems. Instead of plotting the data at the end, just use `fprintf` in MATLAB to output the data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

The following Links show you, how you can implement the serial communication in Java and C++.

**Java** :
http://playground.arduino.cc/interfacing/java

**C++** :
http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/CPPWindows

If you want to write the data stream to a local file, you can do that, for instance, with *ofstream* (C++) or *PrintWriter* (Java).

Furthermore, there are a several additional libraries for other programming languages such as c# (*cmdMessenger*).